# on click open the images as a gallery bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a small snippet of HTML like below

```html
<div class="comment-div">
   <h2>Murtaza Ali <span>15 Aug 2016</span></h2>
   <p>I think if you managed. </p>
   <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo6w.png" alt="Smiley face">
</div>
                       
<div class="comment-div">
   <h2>Suraj Shukla <span>15 Aug 2016</span></h2>
   <p>I think if you managed. </p>
   <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo6w.png" alt="Smiley face">
</div>
                       
<div class="comment-div">
   <h2>Suraj <span>15 Aug 2016</span></h2>
   <p>I think if you managed. </p>
   <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo6w.png" alt="Smiley face">
 </div>
                       
<div class="comment-div">
     <h2>Suraj <span>15 Aug 2016</span></h2>
     <p>I think if you managed. </p>
     <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo6w.png" alt="Smiley face">
</div>
```

Now on the click of the image, I want to open a pop up and then want to swipe to the next image. This is only for mobile so on click need to swipe (right-left)to next image

Please suggest. [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/6a9o82yL/) the fiddle for the same.

Comment: you gotta share what you have tried to do so. People aren't here to write that from scratch

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://codepen.io/krnlde/pen/pGijB

Answer (score 1):

Please check this link here is more related example with different effects.

http://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/gallery%20lightbox/

I hope it will helpful for you.

Thanks